# MQTT without TLS - prevent publish messages from unauthenticated devices

Tags: tcp, jwt

I have an use case where I'm not able to use MQTTS/TLS due to constraint on devices.

Our plan is to perform authentication during MQTT `CONNECT`, passing a JWT token as a password. If I understand correctly MQTT keep a TCP connection open for all subsequent messages.

Given a standard MQTT broker (like HiveMQ, VerneMQ, ...), it is possible for an attacker to `PUBLISH` mqtt message without calling the `CONNECT` first?

Of course they can potentially sniff the JWT token and call the `CONNECT`, but this token will be valid only for a short period of time... And we can also put in place some auditing on `CONNECT` to try to prevent attacks (IP filtering, ...).

I known that in any case this will not be a secure proof solution, but this will be used only on a small set of devices, hopefully for a short period of time.

My concern is if an attacker can just send traffic "on behalf of another TCP connection"? Calling `PUBLISH` without first calling `CONNECT`. Maybe this doesn't make sense ...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the first operation that needs to do after the TCP handshake is a CONNECT. So in theory nobody can send a PUBLISH message on the first MQTT pdu. But I will be worried if the implementation of your devices allows to receive messages without a CONNECT message. So it would be a good idea to verify if the implementation on your devices respect the order, first a CONNECT, by using a library that verify your concerns.